# How to Change Size of Desktop

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, icons, panel

UPDATE:

It appears my icons are appearing below my screen.  This is part of a screenshot, but I cannot see it on my monitor:

[image]

---

I am running Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon.

I changed the size of my panel, and now my desktop icons overflow to underneath the panel.  How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

I want to be able to auto-sort it without it returning to being hidden.

[image]

Comment: Which desktop environment? Did you try moving the icon? Right click > sort by name or whatever?

Comment: Linux Mint 16.  I can move the icon, but when I auto-sort, it goes right back to where it was.

Comment: Yes, I know it's Linux Mint, I'm asking about the desktop environment. Is it cinnamon, gnome, mate, kde, something else?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  It is cinnamon.  Based on Gnome 3 I believe.

Comment: And how did you change the sizeof the panel?I'm asking so I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Right-click on the panel, go to Panel-Settings.  Option is in there. Sorry about the delayed response!

Comment: Which version of cinnamon is this? I can't reproduce your problem on my Cinnamon 2.0.14, every time I resize the panel so that it covers an icon, right click => "Organize Desktop by Name" moves it correctly.

Comment: I'll post specs above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12668/discussion-between-terdon-and-evorlor)

Comment: Hail all.  These mint icons seem to spontaneously re-configure to minimum size.  After 2 x updates back, I thought they were completely gone, only to find them very very small, and some re-positioned behind other windows.   All I've found so far, is that if I select exactly ONE icon, I can right-mouse-click and select "`resize`" -- That is Extremely tedious.  And not as repeatable as a script -- Please answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

me again.  I found one method on Mint forums

> Re: How to Resize desktop icons?
>   Postby lexington523 » Mon Dec 09, 2013 3:13 pm
>
> open file manager
>   click the "edit" menu and then select "preferences"
>   set the "icon view defaults" larger or smaller than 100%
>   this will set all the icon sizes on your desktop at the same time.

This works.  See forum:

- [How to Resize desktop icons?](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152404)

After you resize Cinnamon re-orders the icons.  If refresh doesn't work you can use "`Organize desktop by name`" and then drag them back to where you'd LIKE them to be.

There must be a config file some place with this kind of thing in it -- Yes??